# How to set expected framerate to AVAssetWriterInput

Tags: ios, video, frame-rate, avassetwriter, avassetwriterinput

I have an app which encodes videos in different ways and saves it to Photos library - it can cut specific time range, add pictures, text, etc. Everything is working perfectly till I try to encode video 120+ fps. The problem is that video appears to be slow-motioned and I don't pursue that goal at all.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43365266/how-do-i-control-avassetwriter-to-write-at-the-correct-fps) I found out about property for `AVAssetWritterInput` which is called `AVVideoExpectedSourceFrameRateKey`, but the problem is that when I try to apply this parameter to my `AVAssetWritterInput`, I'm getting this error:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVAssetWriterInput initWithMediaType:outputSettings:sourceFormatHint:] Output settings dictionary contains one or more invalid keys: ExpectedFrameRate'`

Here's my `AVAssetWriterInput` initialization, nothing fancy at all:

```
let input = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, outputSettings: [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG,
                                                                                         AVVideoHeightKey: correctedContentSize.height,
                                                                                         AVVideoWidthKey: correctedContentSize.width,
                                                                                         AVVideoExpectedSourceFrameRateKey: 60])
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I am getting same issue. Did you solve it ?

Comment: Hello @gstream79! If I'm not wrong, key `AVVideoExpectedSourceFrameRateKey ` should be put into `AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey` or something like that. But I don't know for sure because I didn't use this property eventually.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Eugene Alexeev, I've tried to use AVVideoExpectedSourceFrameRateKey but no luck with it.

Comment: How did you solve this problem? You had to give up? or did use another way to set fps ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the way you're placing the key inside of your Dictionary to load the settings into the outputSettings. The key 'AVVideoExpectedSourceFrameRateKey' is actually supposed to go inside a nested Dictionary, and the key for it is 'AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey'. So you have a Dictionary of Dictionaries of sorts as the outputSettings instead. It should look something like this:

```
let outputSettings:[String: Any] = [
            AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG,
            AVVideoHeightKey: correctedContentSize.height,
            AVVideoWidthKey: correctedContentSize.width
            AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey: 
               [AVVideoExpectedSourceFrameRateKey: 60]                                         
        ]
```

More info on this process can be found here if you'd like to use this to adjust the feed when playing this video back:

[AVAssetWriter AVVideoExpectedSourceFrameRateKey (frame rate) ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49235811/avassetwriter-avvideoexpectedsourceframeratekey-frame-rate-ignored)