# Is there any way to give fixed number of frames we can capture in 1 seconds using AVCaptureSession?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I am creating BOOMERANG effect in my app, So i am capturing images by setting 1 sec timer. Currently in 1 sec i am getting around 24 to 30 frames most of the time.

But i want to capture only 28 frames in 1 sec all the time.

Can anyone help me to achieve this please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 1):

On your AVCaptureDeviceInput you will have a video input.

```
    let frameRate = 28
    let frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, frameRate)

    do {
        try videoDevice.unlockForConfiguration()
        videoDevice.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = frameDuration
        videoDevice.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = frameDuration
        videoDevice.lockForConfiguration()
    } catch {
        NSLog("videoDevice lockForConfiguration returned error \(error)")
    }
```

You can try to set the min/max FPS through frame duration.

Comment: i have done this but it will not capture exactly 28 every-time, It is capturing from 24 to 30 frames always.

Comment: hmm, I dont think you can get it exactly, could you do it at the writing level? This post may help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43365266/how-do-i-control-avassetwriter-to-write-at-the-correct-fps